# Leetcode Oracle - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle

I am trying to solve this problem using Oracle SQL but I keep getting this error -

`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

link to problem - https://leetcode.com/problems/department-top-three-salaries/submissions/

my solution until now - just to query the data -

```
with temp as
(
    select d.Name as Department,
    e.Name as Employee,
    e.Salary as Salary
    from employee e
    join department d
    on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
)
select *
, rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as rr
from temp
```

but if i simply run this then it works fine -

```
with temp as
(
    select d.Name as Department,
    e.Name as Employee,
    e.Salary as Salary
    from employee e
    join department d
    on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
)
select *
from temp
```

And if I run this then it runs okay -

```
select department, employee, salary
from
(
select A.* , dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as rr
from
(
select d.Name as Department,
e.Name as Employee,
e.Salary as Salary
from employee e
join department d
on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
) A
) B
where rr <= 3
```

does it mean i cannot use the cascading `with` statements in oracle ?

For instance, cant I write -

```
with temp as 
(
select col1, col2 from table
)

, temp1 as
(
select *, "hello" as col3
from temp
)

select *
from temp1
```

in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select only all the columns then `*` without the alias is fine. But if You need to give alias of the table wherever you want to select all the columns of the table using `*` and also another expression in `SELECT` clause.

```
with TEMP AS 
( SELECT
    COL1,
    COL2
FROM table )
, TEMP1 AS 
(SELECT
    T.*, -- alias here
    "hello"   AS COL3
FROM TEMP T
)
select * FROM TEMP1;

with temp as
(
    select d.Name as Department,
    e.Name as Employee,
    e.Salary as Salary
    from employee e
    join department d
    on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
)
select T.* -- alias here
, rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as rr
from temp T;
```